# Expressing Volatility Smile as One Number

Tags: options, volatility-smile, parameter

Is there an accepted way in academia / industry to express the volatility smile as one number? (Not the full vol surface, but just the smile for a given option maturity: i.e. the implied vol as a function of strike).

The second derivative taken at the money is one of the ideas that came to my mind, i.e. if $f(K)$ is the implied vol and $K$ is the strike:

$$f^{''}(K)\approx\frac{f(K_{ATM}+h)-2f(K_{ATM})+f(K_{ATM}-h)}{h^2}$$ for some $h>0$. But that's just one of many obvious ways to summarize the "curvature" around the ATM point: is there an accepted way of expressing the smile as one number?

Comment: The vol of vol parameter in the sabr model is one candidate

Comment: This might be useful https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15071/volatility-skew-and-how-to-capture-it?rq=1